# Unable to write to Database file

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, raspberrypi

I have set up a raspberry Pi 4 to use as a data server. It runs a Mosquito server with a Node-Red interface handling messages from various ESP32 modules feeding in data. Node-Red interfaces with a  SQLite database within the raspberry pi. The data stream from the ESP modules is very intermittent and the data is only a few dozen bytes at one time.

The issue is reading and writing to the database from a local PC running Linux Mint. I can use a VNC viewer to interface with the database using a SQLite Browser running on the Raspberry Pi, but I would rather use the DB Browser on the Linux Mint machine and interface with the DB file on the Raspberry Pi through a shared Samba connection.

I set up the Samba connection and set the Samba configuration file as below.

**[pishare]
path = /home/pi/shared
writeable=Yes
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
public=yes**

I set the share folder permissions to read/write execute for anyone.

From my Linux Mint machine I can connect to the shared folder and open the database with my Linux based Sqlite DB Browser, but if I try to make a change I get the message: **“Could not commit view changes. Error message: attempt to write a readonly database”**

I can, however, create a text document, revise it and save it within the shared folder, so it does not seem to be a problem with Samba.

Can anyone give me some Idea why I cannot write to my DB through Samba, but it works fine if I do it through the VNC viewer?

( I have searched for similar issues but nothing seems to fit my specific problem)

Thank You
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You missed the setting higher up in the Homes section to allow it to be writable. Though it does seem strange you can create files in it if it is still set to the yes. When I setup my share using the same settings as you for it except mine is public=no, it refused to allow me to create files in the share until that was set and samba restarted.

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
read only = no
```